# How to find the unicode control string received by emacs for a command?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, ssh, keystrokes

I usually ssh into a machine at my university and run emacs on screen.
I want to figure out what unicode strings code for a particular command ?
For example when I changed the preferences in my OSX terminal app and associated the following actions to keyboard buttons then Emacs interpreted them as useful command.

```
Button  Action  Keystroke
end     \005    CTRL+e
home    \001    CTRL+a
pgdown  \026    CTRL+v
pgup    \033v   ESC v
```

I want to make more such bindings. For example if I could find out the right action for "Ctrl+_"(Undo) then I could associate that to one of the useless function keys.

So basically how can I find out what "Action" triggers a Keystroke ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. In any buffer, do a [quoted insert](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html) of the key sequence. For example:

   <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd>

   Instead of calling `move-end-of-line` (the command that `C-e` is bound to by default), Emacs will insert `^E` at point.
2. Hit <kbd>C-b</kbd> to put point on the character you just inserted, then do <kbd>C-x =</kbd> (bound to `what-cursor-position`). Emacs will print relevant information about the character at point in the minibuffer. For `^E`, you'll see this:

   > Char: C-e (5, #o5, #x5) point=1 of 1 (0%) column=0

   This tells you that the character code for `C-e` is `5` in octal, `#o5` in decimal, and `#x5` in hex.

Following these steps for the other key sequences you listed, it looks like "Actions" are derived from the decimal notation:

```
| Key Sequence | Output of C-x =               | Action |
|--------------+-------------------------------+--------|
| ^E           | Char: C-e (5, #o5, #x5)       | \005   |
| ^A           | Char: C-a (1, #o1, #x1)       | \001   |
| ^V           | Char: C-v (22, #o26, #x16)    | \026   |
| ^[           | Char: ESC (27, #o33, #x1b)    | \033   |
|--------------+-------------------------------+--------|
```

In short:

```
| Char code | Action |
|-----------+--------|
| #o5       | \005   |
| #o1       | \001   |
| #o26      | \026   |
| #o33      | \033   |
|-----------+--------|
```

So you'll need to follow this pattern when determining the correct "Action" for a given char code.